# Update database from model - Entity Framework

Tags: sql, frameworks, azure, entity

Is it possible in any way to just update the database schema from entity model..? So that all the information in the database stays in the database? When you generate database from model the information will get lost.. I work against SQL Azure, and I have not found any tool to manage the tables and realations in the SQL Azure database in a proper way.. It would be soo nice if it could be done by the Entity Framework designer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be resolved (from an entity framework point of view) in the next EF release.
From an azure point of view you can use [SQL Azure Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/).