# Update Database from Model (when model changed)?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-model-first

I'm developing an application (for my education, not commercial) using MVC3 and Model First approach.

I created a model and generated the SQL CE 4 database from it.

Next, I may need to change my model - i.e. add a column to a table, which is not a primary or foreign key column.

I only see an option "Generate Database From Model", which will drop my database and create a new one.

Is there a way to "Update Database From Model", which will preserve the database and just add the new columns, populating them with some default values or nulls?

A similar question 
[Update database from model - Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979910/update-database-from-model-entity-framework)
was asked last year and suggested that the solution may become available in the future - but did anything change since then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a package that takes care of that. It's EntityFramework.Migrations in NuGet repository. There's a good read for that :
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EntityFrameworkCodeFirstMigrationsAlphaNuGetPackageOfTheWeek10.aspx

Package itself is on :
http://nuget.org/List/Packages/EntityFramework.Migrations

It was also presented  by Scott Hanselman on  MIX 11  http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM02 (really awesome video showing usage of scaffolding, elmah, glimpse and more )

Answer (score 1):

also see this [msdn article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/21/code-first-migrations-alpha-3-released.aspx)
the page  has a couple of links for walkthroughs on using the migrations tools

Answer (score 0):

Updating the answer from @torm with what I've found in the NuGet page

> The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the package
>   is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore.